# how to Implement ABAC Access Control for the Openstack in C#?

Tags: openstack, abac

Implement ABAC Access Control for the Openstack in C# to apply it in real enviroment.
/etc/keystone.conf and XACML policy write ...

Comment: Can you be more specific? What have you tried? Did you look into ABAC solutions e.g. Axiomatics (where I work)?

Comment: First of all thank you. when i edit keystone configuration file i don't exactly know places of section code to apply new code of ABAC such as abac code , connect to policy file and .....

Comment: I want change RBAC to ABAC model in openstack.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, ABAC can be applied in an OpenStack cloud environment. Unfortunately, since we don't have much information about what you are trying to achieve, I can only speak in generalities.

C# is a supported programming language for SDKs for XACML implementations, such as the company I work for, Axiomatics.

OpenStack can be used with certain API gateways that would allow fine grain access control/ ABAC. While I don't have much OpenStack experience, I suggest reading about Trio2o and IBM® OpenStack based on my searches. Any API Gateway with sufficient features will do the track though.

Comment: Thank you.For Openstack SDK : NuGet is a free and open-source package manager designed for the Microsoft development platform. I want practice experience to be implement this issue.I have read all these things for a while and lack practical implementation. thank you again